# Запись и чтение одной Entity из разных схем одной БД

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Есть Spring Boot приложение, версии 2.0 Есть необходимость писать и читать одну и туже Entity в разные схемы одной базы данных(PostgreSQL), посредством Hibernate.

Comment: В чем проблема заключается? Что не получается? По факту нет никаких припятсвий. Опишите более подробно и приведите код(саму сущность, конфигурацию и т.д.) с чем возникает проблема

Comment: проблема как раз с конфигурацией, не могу понять как её правильно расписать, всё остальное очень стандартное

Comment: Если таблиц две - то можно использовать `@SecondaryTable`. Но лучше сделайте все отдельно. Разные схемы по факту - разные БД. А если в одной таблице что-то добавится, а во второй не надо будет?

Answer (score 1):

Создайте базовую сущность и опишите в ней все поля.
Потом для каждой таблицы создайте дочерние классы, унаследовавшись от базовой сущности и расставьте аннотации @Table с указанием имени и схемы и таблицы.